# SQL Server: problem with UDF

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a function and select statement

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fun_currentday ( @dt DATETIME)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @currentday DATETIME
    SET @currentday = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @dt), 0)
    RETURN (@currentday)
END
GO

DECLARE @pvm AS DATETIME
SET @pvm = GETDATE()

SELECT     'Last 7 days' AS Range, dbo.fun_currentday(@pvm) - 6 AS Stday, dbo.fun_currentday(@pvm) AS Endday
```

All works fine but when I hover over dbo.fun_currentday at the select statement, I get an error saying:

```
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fun_currentday", or the name is ambiguous.
```

Where's the problem?

Comment: I still have the same problem. I tried to run this on new instance where there is no such function. And still have the same problem.

Comment: I ran your script, and it worked just fine for me. The function was created, and the subsequent query returned the week range as expected. No errors or even warnings. Naturally, when I tried running it once again, it produced the error that the function already existed, but the query that used the function still worked and gave the same result.

Comment: So, the error you've got has most probably been caused by the absence of the function. But why the function turned out to be absent, I can't say for sure.

Comment: Something pretty odd is happening. When I disconnected my session to the instance and connected again, the warning message disappeared!

Comment: Martin's answer explains it well. Turns out I've encountered similar problems too, but I didn't know the easy solution anyway, nor did I have any good explanation to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intellisense / Error highlighting always does this for newly created objects. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to refresh the local cache.

### Before

[image: Before]

### After

[image: After]

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut! Didn't know it was possible without reconnecting. Should have suspected though.

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure have to be stored somewhere so when you don't specify the location it goes to default database (master). So you should call it like

```
SELECT 'Last 7 days' AS Range,master.dbo.fun_currentday(GETDATE()) - 6 AS Stday, master.dbo.fun_currentday(GETDATE()) AS Endday
```

EDITED

I've checked that and I wasn't right, it not always goes to mater schema. It goes to database in contex of you were woring, so if your create procedure was created in query on root folder it goes to master, but if you created it in query of test databse you should use `test.dbo.fun_currentday(GETDATE())`. To avoid it always specify the databse like `USE database_name GO CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fun_currentday`

Comment: When trying to create straight into database, I get an errorMsg 166, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
'CREATE/ALTER FUNCTION' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 6

Comment: Yeah, it's SQL Server try USE database_name GO CREATE FUNCTION instread. Corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Everything runs fine here with SQL Server 2008 Express.

Have you tried running your query on a different database?
You can try to create a new schema and create you UDF in it.

Make sure you have the necessary permissions and that the dbo schema configuration is correct.

Comment: Yes, I have tried running it against master database, and Testidb. Either way, I still have this same problem

Comment: Have you tried leveling up the compatibility level of your database?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008, compatibility level is 100. Problem solved, see above.